# Ignore non-existant DocumentRoot in httpd

Tags: arch-linux, vmware-workstation, httpd

My server is located on a VM, and the folder `/srv/http` resolves to a symlinked shared folder at `/mnt/hgfs/sandbox.dev/site`. Is there a way to either tell `httpd` to ignore this OR to fix it to where the warning does not generate, so the VMHGFS client can connect the shared drive?

I am using ArchLinux

Comment: Is that mount readable/writeable by the httpd user?

Comment: Yes it is. The problem is the the daemon handling the hgfs loads AFTER httpd

Comment: So why not load the httpd after the hgfs is loaded? You might be able to set a delay for the start or change the httpd startup to contain a dependency for hgfs? There probably is a number of ways to influence that behavior.

Comment: Thing is that I have no idea how to do that

Comment: So did you use [google](https://www.google.de/search?q=arch+linux+delay+service+start) to try to find out?  Another alternative would be to not have it start automatically but rather have a custom startup scripts that waits until the share is available and starts the httpd after that's the case. There are literally dozens of options to set this up.